# Cannot get file output using QProcess in python

Tags: python, file, qprocess

I need to:
1. Capture the output of a process in a log file, but
2. Do it detached, since the program can take hours, (or days).

Apparently, if you use QProcess.startDetached(command), you lose your StandardOutput, so that

```
launchApp = QtCore.QProcess()        
launchApp.setStandardOutputFile("logfile")
launchSim.startDetached("my_command")
```

does not work.

```
launchSim.start("my_command")
```

DOES work, but I can't afford the tie-up.
Also

```
launchSim.startDetached("my_command", " > logfile")
```

does not work.  It sees
"> logfile" as an illegal option to "my_command"

This is on Linux

---

The problem is that "my_command" dies when the calling program closes.  nohup doesn't seem to help.  (Not sure why).

Answer (score 1):

How about using `os.system()` from the standard lib:

```
import os
os.system("nohup my_command > logfile &")
```

probably a bit better and safer would be:

```
import os
os.system("nohup /full/path/to/my_command >& logfile &")
```

Notice the redirection of both output streams and the full path to command. Also you might be interested to look at `os.popen()` and the `subprocess` module.